# Finding Convergence and Lowest Meeting Point of Sequential Sums from Two or More Lists

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I have multiple lists of numbers, such as:

a = {52, 4};
b = {60, 12};

My goal is to create sequences from these lists by starting at the initial sum of the numbers in each list and then continuing by adding numbers from the same list, in the order they appear (from left to right).

For example:

- 60 (initial value) + 52 + 4 + 52 + 4

and not:

- 60 + 52 + 52 + 4
- 60 + 4 + 52 + 4

I'm looking to determine whether two or more such sequences will ever have a common point of intersection. If they do, how can I find the lowest point at which they converge? Additionally, I'd like to know if there is a method to check if it's even possible for these sequences to intersect.

To clarify, we start with initial values of 56 and 72 for the respective lists, and the objective is to find the smallest number at which these two values will meet by adding numbers from the lists in the specified order (sequential sums). Is there a way to calculate the lowest meeting point, and can we establish whether convergence is possible between these sequences?